# Check if a point is on a plane? (Minimize the use of multiplications and divisions)

Tags: geometry, 3d, floating-point

In $\mathbb R3$, given a plane $\mathcal P$ defined by three 3D points points $v_0, v_1, v_2$, I want to check if another point $p$ belongs to that plane, *while avoiding the use of multiplications and divisions as much as possible*.

The reason is to mitigate the floating point errors incurred by the computer representation of decimal numbers.

---

My current method is:

1. Compute the general form of the plane equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$

   Where $a,b,c$ are the components of the plane's unit normal vector
   $N={(v_1-v_0)\times(v_2-v_0) \over \|(v_1-v_0)\times(v_2-v_0)\|}$

   And $d=N.v_0$
2. Plug point $p$ into the plane equation: $res=a.p_x+b.p_y+c.p_z-d$

   If the result is null, the point lies on the plane

   Because of floating point errors, I actually check if the result is "almost" null: $|res|<\epsilon$

However, in certain cases, when I plug $v_2$ into the plane equation, I find that it does not belong to the plane, even though I used $v_2$ to compute the equation in the first place. (I obtain a result bigger than my $\epsilon$.)

This is due to floating point errors. See my question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21916606/143504

So I am looking for an alternate method that would mitigate these errors.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html could be of some use?

Comment: you only need two points to define a plane.

Comment: @TKM If I project `p` on one of the vector (I assume you mean `v1-v0` or `v2-v0`), its components will change in all cases (on the plane or not), right?

Comment: yes. Another method is to project p onto each of the two vectors and then add the projections to see if you get p.

Comment: Why do you think that multiplication is the source of your errors? I'm not an expert in numerical analysis, but one of the first things I learnt is that [subtraction is one of the biggest sources of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). Your choice of which vertex to call $v_0$ might have a big effect.

Answer (score 7):

Four points lie in a common plane if the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 \\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

is zero. This has the benefit that it requires no divisions at all. It does require quite some multiplications, though.

You might however want to have a look at [Shewchuk's page on *Adaptive Precision Floating-Point Arithmetic and Fast Robust Predicates for Computational Geometry*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html), where you can find papers on how to evaluate these predicates *exactly*, and also a C implementation doing just this.

As an alternative, you might want to use one of [CGALs](http://www.cgal.org/) [exact predicates kernels](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/index.html#title9).

Note however that if your input points are double coordinates, then a point lying *exactly* on a plane spanned by three others is rather unlikely. So be sure that you don't make conceptual mistakes there.

Your statement about using $\epsilon$ when interpreting the result shows that you are aware of the numeric imprecision involved. However, I'm unsure how you'd decide on what values for $\epsilon$ are reasonable. That may depend on your application. Only then can you judge in which direction you'd rather err.

Comment: I'd love to know more about this. I still don't understand the nature of determinants. Is there some explanation or proof of this property?

Comment: @Dani: A point in the plane spanned by $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ (in $\mathbb R^3$ and not collinear) can be described as $P_1+\mu_2(P_2-P_1)+\mu_3(P_3-P_1)$ or $\mu_1P_1+\mu_2P_2+\mu_3P_3$ with $\mu_1=1-\mu_2-\mu_3$. So if a point $P_4$ is to be on that plane, you have to solve four equations: $\mu_1x_1+\mu_2x_2+\mu_3x_3=x_4$, same for $y$ and $z$, and $\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3=1$.  This is an overdetermined inhomogeneous system of equations. Moving the right hand side to the left you obtain $4$ equations in $4$ variables, with $(0,0,0,0)$ always a solution and a non-zero solution only if the det is zero.

Comment: And does this work for flat planes with 4D points?

Comment: @TegLouis: You can use the same approach to check whether 5 points in 4d lie on a common hyperplane (i.e. 3-dimensional affine subspace). For 4 points in 4d lying on a 2-dimensional plane this does not work, as it treats the columns as homogeneous coordinates.